# Need help translating python code (with Numpy) to Matlab equivalent

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, neural-network, xor

I'm working on a XOR Neural Network, that uses a Sigmoid activation function.
I have a working python code but I need to translate one of the lines into a code that MATLAB understands. I have looked up the documentation on NumPy and I know that it has it's own array operators. I just cannot put together a working MATLAB equivalent for `dH`. This portion is in an explicit for-loop.

    `dZ = E * sigmoid_(Z)                        # delta Z
    dH = dZ.dot(Wz.T) * sigmoid_(H)             # delta H`

An explanation would also help me to further my understanding. If my full code is required don't hesitate to ask, but I know that it will not be needed.

Comment: dZ is a normal product and dZ.dot(Wz.T) is a Matrix product times a vector.

Comment: http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-python-xref.pdf here you find numpy commands and the translated matlab commands

Comment: It would help if you gave the shapes (e.g. `E.shape`, `Wz.shape`) for all the input variables.  I assume they are all numpy arrays.

Comment: @MaxKrappmann Thanks. I have gone through the mathesaurus resources and several others. Their equivalency is the same when it comes to `dot()` but it doesn't explain how a variable in front of it changes it from an array dot product to a matrix multiplying by an array. I thank you for that information. They are not the same size.

Comment: E =  (4 1) dH = (4 3)

Comment: In matlab or in python? (keep in mind that the order of the function arguments will also be changed!!!!).  otherwise just look at the matlab results and transpose your matrix or vector to keep track of the correct dimensions. I had to go through the same translating an image normalization from matlab to python.

Comment: @MaxKrappmann So in python dZ.dot(Wz.T), where dZ is the vector and Wz is the matrix transposed? or is it the other way around. I would've liked for you to submit this  as an answer so that I may accept it. Lol.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you create a function that calculates (dZ, dH) from Z and H. With y = (Z, H):

```
function dy = myODE(t,y)
  dy(1) = E * sigmf_(y(1), [a b])
  dy(2) = dy(1).dot(W*y(1).T) * sigmf_(y(2), [a b])
```

Source: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab

```
    dZ = E * sigmoid_(Z)                        # delta Z
    dH = dZ.dot(Wz.T) * sigmoid_(H)             # delta H
```

dZ uses Matrix product (dot product)

Matlab: a * b 
matrixmultiply(a,b)

The dH Term can be reproduced with the np.dot
But sometimes the Matlab dot product:

```
Vector dot product, u · v dot(u,v) dot(u,v)
```

vs yours:

```
dZ.dot(Wz.T)
```

It is likely that in python this equals

```
dot(W.T,dZ)
```